What is the number of all possible k clusters for N data points?
Assume that we have N data points and we divide into k clusters.
What is the number of all possible k clusters for N data points?

Is this a homework question? If yes, please, edit your post to add the tag [tag:homework]. For these questions, we shouldn't reveal the complete answer. That's why. Thanks for creating a post with a clear title, but please also include some context in your posts, like "what are your findings or ideas?"

No, it is not a HW question.

Is the value of $k$ fixed?

yes, it is  fixed.

Please, use also the [tag:math] tag then when your question is purely mathematical, and if it requires a proof, use the tag [tag:proofs]. If this is not a homework question, then where did you find it? Provide more context in your posts. If you just came up with this question, which I doubt, then you should say that. Also, edit your post to clarify that k is fixed because comments are temporary and can be deleted.

We denote the number as $S(N,k)$ and recall obvious special cases as follows.
$S(N,1)=1$: All points belong to one cluster.
$S(N,N)=1$: Each point is in its own cluster.
$S(N,k)=0$, if $k>N$: It is impossible to have more clusters than points.
For the more general case, refer Stirling number of the second kind.

In mathematics, particularly in combinatorics, a Stirling number of the second kind (or Stirling partition number) is the number of ways to partition a set of n objects into k non-empty subsets and is denoted by ${\displaystyle S(n,k)}$ or ${\displaystyle \textstyle \left\{{n \atop k}\right\}}$.


${\displaystyle \left\{{n \atop k}\right\}={\frac {1}{k!}}\sum _{i=0}^{k}(-1)^{k-i}{\binom {k}{i}}i^{n}=\sum _{i=0}^{k}{\frac {(-1)^{k-i}i^{n}}{(k-i)!i!}}.}$


Stirling numbers of the second kind obey the recurrence relation ${\displaystyle \left\{{n+1 \atop k}\right\}=k\left\{{n \atop k}\right\}+\left\{{n \atop k-1}\right\}\quad {\mbox{for}}\;0<k<n}$
with initial conditions ${\displaystyle \left\{{n \atop n}\right\}=1\quad {\mbox{ for}}\;n\geq 0\quad {\text{ and }}\quad \left\{{n \atop 0}\right\}=\left\{{0 \atop n}\right\}=0\quad {\text{ for }}n>0{\text{.}}}$


cinch handles the general case, but since you say that $k$ is fixed, there's a simpler approach:
Assuming each cluster must contain at least one element, we need to distribute the remaining $N-k$ elements. Each is assigned to one of $k$ possibilities, and since each such assignment is independent of the others, we can just multiply those together. So there are $k^\left(N-k\right)$ possible assignments.
(In addition to assuming fixed $k$, this also assumes that it matters which point is assigned to which cluster, not just what the cluster sizes are.)
